# Should I turn on/off my iPad's WiFi every time I need it?

Tags: ipad, wifi

My question is pretty clear and simple: When exactly should I turn on/off my iPad's WiFi?

There are two possibilities:

- keeping it on forever
- turning it on/off based on my needs

**Note:** I need internet almost 100 times per day.

Well which one? Whether **saving battery** is more important or protecting WiFi?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking… What do you mean by "protecting of WiFi"?

Comment: @ruddfawcett I think if I turn on/off multiple times, it will be broken. So I guess if I keep it on, it will be protected *(health perspective)*

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your question. Check out [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and clarify your question with some more information.

Comment: @ruddfawcett Well what's vague now? All of my question is: *"Should I turn on/off my iPad's WiFi every time I need it? or keep is on forever?"*

Comment: Are you concerned about the wifi chip breaking?

Comment: @PoisonNinja Kinda .. I scare if I turn WiFi off/on several times, it will be broken ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to turn your iPad's wifi off.

You might save some battery life by turning off background refresh.

```
General > Background App Refresh > Toggle All or Some OFF
```

But it is my personal opinion that the ease of use that you gain from not having to log in and out of the wifi is worth keeping it on.

Comment: I agree here. If, as you say, you "need [the] internet almost 100 times per day" than it seems like a waste of time to toggle it on and off and wait for it to reconnect. Plus, you aren't actually saving [*that* much battery](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/does-having-wifi-always-on-drain-your-battery-more.1396891/).